# Substitution in double integral

Tags: integration, substitution

Suppose I have an integral of the form

$$\iint f(x)g(y)dxdy$$

Can I make a substitution for x and y such that they both depend on the same parameter eg.

$x=h(t), y=h’(t)$?

Comment: That would take you from a double integral to a contour integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a genuine double integral, since it factorizes into:
$$
\int f(x)dx\int g(y)dy
$$
Now you can make a substitution with the same function or different functions for both $x$ and  $y$, however don't be trapped into giving the new variable the same name $t$ in both cases - you are not allowed to do that, the integration variables still remain different.